# Is there a lint rule for forbidding the usage of .js files? (prefer .ts)

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, lint, file-extension

So I have a project which was built with "*.js" files.
We started using typescript and I want to force new files to have the ".ts" suffix
Is there a lint for forcing it? Is it even possible to write such lint code?
I tried to use '[eslint-plugin-filenames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-filenames)' but it doesn't check file's extension

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use this in tsconfig compiler option to disallow importing of js files:

```
{"compilerOptions": {
"allowJs": false }}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs

Comment: I have lots of of js files right now that I don't have the time to migrate yet.
I was hoping to add a rule and add lint-disable comment in the existing files.
I found a way to achieve it kinda, but I'm looking for a way that will have better error message. By adding this to the lint config
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [ ".js" ],
      "rules": {
        "max-len": ["warn", 0]
      }
    }
  ]